# Sorting multiple columns in linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I want to sort a file having multiple columns, like if one unique entry of the first column is sorted, then sort the 2nd column related to that first entry. For example my input file is this:

```
192.168.1.10 10 www.google.it
192.168.4.10 14 www.google.it
192.168.1.10 20 www.google.it
192.168.1.10 15 www.google.it
192.168.5.10 11 www.google.it
192.168.6.10 31 www.google.it
192.168.1.10 24 www.google.it
192.168.6.10 25 www.google.it
```

And if I want to sort it in linux shell, it should become like this:

```
192.168.1.10 10 www.google.it
192.168.1.10 15 www.google.it
192.168.1.10 20 www.google.it
192.168.1.10 24 www.google.it
192.168.4.10 14 www.google.it
192.168.5.10 11 www.google.it
192.168.6.10 25 www.google.it
192.168.6.10 31 www.google.it
```

How to do it?

Comment: use `sort <filename>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man sort`, and you'll get the following output:

```
-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
       start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line). See POS syntax below
```

The `sort` command does support multi-level soring, for exmaple:

```
sort -t ',' -k1,1 -k3,3 test.txt
```

will sort *test.txt* first by the first column, and then, the third column.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
sort file
```

that should do the trick

Comment: Really? for this kind of answer you can leave a comment like I do.